# I have some problems with straight lines and planes

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Firstly, I need to say that English is not my first language and the problems were written in Spanish. I have never read a Math problem in English, so some words may be confusing. If they are, please let me know.

In this problem, they gave me a equation of the plane:
$$x - 2y + 3z = 8 $$ 
A straight line:
$$L1: \frac{x+4}{4}= \frac{5-z}{3}, y = -1$$

So they asked me to get the equation of the straight line that passes through a point and is parallel to the plane, and cuts the line $L1$.

What I have done is the following:

Firstly I changed the equation of the line to symmetric equation
$$x = -4 + 4n$$
$$y = -1$$
$$z = 5 - 3n$$

Now I know the equation of the line is $P(-4, -1, 5) +  n(4, 0, -3)$

Now I also know that the answer will be the sum of the point that they gave me (which is $(0, 2, -1)$) and something else.

The "something else" is the thing I don't know how to get.

I hope this is enough to be accepted for a homework question. I solved a lot of other problems, but I can't solve this one though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the intersection point of the 2 lines as P. As P lies on L1, it should satisfy the parametric form you have put in the qn. Then, the vector of the line is $\vec{P}-\vec{A}$ where A is the point mentioned in the qn. This should be orthogonal to the normal of the plane.

So $(\vec{P}-\vec{A})\cdot\hat{n}=0$

With $\vec{A}$, $\hat{n}$ known and $\vec{P}$ in the form of a single variable, solve and obtain P. Then calculate the line through A and P.

Comment: Ok so it should be -4+4n+6+18-9n= 0. n = 4 and the answer should be starting from A + n(4, -1, -2)